# about visual studio multi-language switch

Tags: visual-studio, language-packs

I've already installed the latest version of visual studio 2017 (15.3.3) with two language package installed same time: English and Chinese.

But only one of them could be select in visual studio's option.
When I installed both, in the option, there are only two choice "Chinese" and "Same As Microsoft Windows". Only if when I uninstall Chinese package, English option will there. Vice versa.

Is there any easy solution that I could switch multi-language in the option directly but not install/unintall each time?

Answer (score 0):

After several times installed and uninstalled. I think there may be bug for the visual studio installation.

If I installed other language pack first time beside English, here is Chinese, the choice of language option "English" do NOT show after installed complete even I confirmed English language was selected and installed.

But if I installed ONLY "English" the first time and then update with a newly language pack the secound time, multiple langauges are all shown and could switch to each other with restarting.